# Session Hijacking? X-Forwarded-For, different between Login and subsequent request

Tags: php, asp.net, security, authentication, session-hijacking

When user login into the web application, I capture 3 values and stored it in session state:

```
IP 
UserAgent 
http-X-Forwarded-For
```

During login, http-x-forwarded-for has empty value. The log file shows that, the http-x-forwarded-for has a new value when user assessing the home page, something like 10.0.0.45. What could this means?

Should I end the session? or just load an empty page to the client?
Is this some sort of hijacking?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? This can add the header. This IP is an internal one too, so this is likely.